# cp -r without hidden files

Tags: linux, bash, cp

I have two directories and one is empty.

The first directory has many sub directories with hidden files. When I `cp -r` content from  first directory to the second one, the hidden files gets copied too. Any solutions to escape them?

Comment: it's doable, but removing them after the copy might be simpler

Comment: yeah, but coping the hidden files to other locations is a security hazard in my case.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

You can use `rsync` instead of `cp`:

```
rsync -av --exclude=".*" src dest
```

This excludes hidden files and directories. If you only want to exclude hidden directories, add a slash to the pattern:

```
rsync -av --exclude=".*/" src dest
```

Comment: Any overheads when compared with cp?

Comment: @Rahul It did not occur to me to benchmark it, but I think you shouldn't worry about that

Comment: It works cool! Thanks man!

Just for information, rsync would be great when file size is big, but equal to cp in case the smaller files.

Comment: rsync is much powerful than cp in all aspects.so you should use rsync as your file transferring tool

Comment: Doesn't seem to ignore hidden files in subdirectories (on macOS Big Sur, at least)

Comment: @ndtreviv Just tried it, works as expected with both Apple shipped `rsync` and the one installed with `brew`.

Comment: @EugeneYarmash Weird. I'm getting a .git directory in a subdirectory coming across with this command. ‍♂️

Answer (score 45):

You can do

```
cp -r SRC_DIR/* DEST_DIR
```

to exclude all .files and .dirs in the SRC_DIR level, but still it would copy any hidden files in the next level of sub-directories.

Comment: That's exactly the problem.. :)

Comment: But it works for GIT-Repos, if you don't wan't to copy the whole GIT-Index in .git/ ...

Comment: I +'d this answer because this is the solution I was looking for. I don't want to exclude all invisibles up the tree, just the invisibles at the root level!

Comment: Another variant `cp SOURCE/[!.]* TARGET`.

Answer (score 5):

**rsync** has "-C" option

http://rsync.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html

**Example:**

```
rsync -vazC  dir1 dir2
```

Comment: You are right. I tried **mkdir -p dir1/subdir; touch  dir1/subdir/.cvs; rsync -avzC dir1 dir2**

Comment: rsync -av --exclude=".*" src dest works great. Refer the answer above by eugene. Thanks anyway! :)

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same need when I wanted to copy the files contained in a git repo, but excluding the `.git` folder, while using git bash.

If you don't have access to `rsync`, you can replicate the behavior of `--exclude=".*"` by using the `find` command along with `xargs`:

```bash
find ./src_dir -type f -not -path '*/.*' | xargs cp --parents -t ./dest_dir
```

To give more details:

- `find ./src_dir -type f -not -path '*/.*'` will find all files in `src_dir` excluding the ones where the path contain a `.` at the beginning of a file or folder.
- `xargs cp --parents -t ./dest_dir` will copy the files found to `dest_dir`, recreating the folder hierarchy thanks to the `--parents` argument.

Note: This will not copy empty folders. And will effectively exclude all hidden files and folders from being copied.

Link to relevant doc:

https://linux.die.net/man/1/cp

https://linux.die.net/man/1/find